# Piictu: How did they build the UI?

Tags: iphone, user-interface

Just came across the Piictu iOS app ([Screenshot](http://pttrns.com/www/imgcache/320x480/screens/timeline/Piictu_Social-Networking.png)).

The UI looks great and I was wondering how they did it and what elements they used.

Is it a `UINavigationController` with a custom navigationBar and toolBar?
Or did they use a `UITabbarController`?

The left button in the [detail view](http://pttrns.com/www/imgcache/320x480/screens/photos/Piictu_Social-Networking_01.png) toggles between an overview and a more detailed view, which makes me think they used a `UINavigationController` with a custom background and two buttons...

Comment: Looks like a NavController and a ToolBar to me, along with lots of custom images (like the custom tabs at the top).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea. Looks like a navigation controller with a customized nav bar (see http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/ for an example) and either a custom toolbar or just a UIView containing a couple of buttons.